# When copying all streams from a mkv contained to another mkv container, original cover thumbnail stream gets copied, but does not get visualized

Tags: ffmpeg, video, matroska

So, to simplify the topic for this question, I am using a simple command that only copies all the original streams and puts their copies in a new mkv container.

The original cover.png stream is still in the new container. However, while in the original mkv file, its cover is displayed in the Windows File Explorer, the new mkv file produced by copying its streams does not have its cover displayed when viewing the files in Windows File Explorer.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, if it's a bug on the FFmpeg part, or if it's just something that should not be possible. I have thought of a way around this limitation, which could be to first extract the cover into an individual png file and then add it as a new cover to the new mkv file. However, I would prefer to go this route only if there is no proper way to directly copy the cover.

For easy replication of the problem, here are two different commands for obtaining an mkv video with a working cover thumbnail (one of them uses yt-dlp and FFmpeg, the other uses only FFmpeg).

```
yt-dlp.exe --embed-thumbnail --convert-thumbnails png --embed-metadata -o hasthumb.mkv URL
```

.

```
ffmpeg -i download.mkv -map 0:V -map 0:a -c copy -attach cover.png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic -metadata:s:2 mimetype=image/png hasthumb2.mkv
```

And here is the comand that I am using for copying the streams into a new mkv file, with the produced file having a not working cover thumbnail

```
ffmpeg -i hasthumb.mkv -map 0 -c copy output.mkv
```

The video, audio AND the img thumbnail streams get copied in the last example, but the thumbnail does not get displayed in the Windows File Explorer

Answer (score 0):

So, while I still have not figured out how to do it properly, or if it's even possible to do it with only one command, I have figured out how to do it using two commands in two steps

First, we extract the image from the original video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:v -map -0:V -c copy cover.png
```

Then, we attach it again to the video, removing the old attached image in the process:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:V -map 0:a -c copy -attach cover.png -metadata:s:t mimetype=image/png newvideo.mkv
```

It still seems a little too complicated for something that should be a simple copy and paste of all streams. So, if someone figures out a better way to do it in one command line, I would still appreciate it.